# Issue using heatmap angular 8

Tags: heatmap

I'm having trouble using heatmap.js with Angular 8.
It works fine while serving it live, but I get the following error when I run the production build:

> ERROR TypeError: "setting getter-only property "data""

on my component

```js
  import * as h337 from 'heatmap.js';
  .
  .
  .
  heatmap() {
  ...
  const heatmap = h337.create(options);
  const datos = {
              max: this.max,
              min: this.min,
              data: data
  };
  heatmap.setData(datos);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and then when I updated angular from 8.0 to 8.2 neither the serving worked. As it turned out there is a problem with the img.data being explicitly set (search for the error you will find more details). 
There is an already opened issue at https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js but it seems that the latest merge in the project was 3 years ago and it is not that active.
So either you fix the bug yourself (in your forked version of the repo) or you use an already forked repo.
I did the second and it seems to work fine. The only thing you need to do is replace the heatmap.js dependency in your package.json.

```
npm install --save https://github.com/ionata/heatmap.js.git
```

so at the end your package.json will have this entry:

```
"heatmap.js": "git+https://github.com/ionata/heatmap.js.git"
```